# A short Introduction text to Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, book-recommendation

I was looking for a "short" textbook or lecture notes to undergrad Algebra, with focus on Rings, Fields and Groups.

For "short", I meant that I need something around 200 pages or less.

Comment: Topics in algebra Herstein

Comment: Wow, thanks. That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not advise using Herstein's book. It's quite terse and hard to follow if you are looking for a truly introductory text. I would recommend Joseph Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra* or John Durbin's *Modern Algebra*. Another possibility is Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra*, though this is usually a text used in first year graduate courses, so it may be a bit advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I really enjoyed Fraleigh's book.

*Fraleigh, John B.*, A first course in abstract algebra. 2nd ed, Addison-Wesley Series in Mathematics. Reading, Mass. etc.: Addison-Wesley Publishing Company. XVIII, 455 p. (1976). [ZBL0365.00007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0365.00007).

Sorry,  it's a little longer than I remembered. ..
Maybe try Herstein's book.   Still remember his description of the distributive property as *interweaving* multiplication and addition...